# How to skip trailing zeroes from a decimal with f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, f-string

I want to set a precision in my f-strings, but I do not want the the trailing zeroes in the decimal part.

```
i = 1002
print(f'{i/1000:.2f}') # 1.00 but this must be 1

i = 1009
print(f'{i/1000:.2f}') # 1.01, this is correct
```

The first `print` must be `1`, my expected behavior is seen in the second `print` where it is `1.01`.

I tried `:g` but it works for the first `print` but fails for the second.

```
i = 1000
print(f'{i/1000:.2g}') # 1, this is correct but
i = 1009
print(f'{i/1000:.2g}') # 1, but this must be 1.01
```

One way I tried is `f'{i/1000:.2f}'.strip('.0')` but I wanted to know if there is a better way.

Edit :

In my actual code if `i` is `100000` then the denominator will also be 100000 (smallest digit in the order of `i`) in other words the denominator in my code will always be such that the i//denominator will always yield a single digit.

Comment: This `f'{i/1000:.2f}'.strip('.0')` is bad idea if integers might appear - if `i=100000` then you would get `1`.

Comment: @Daweo in my actual code if it is `100000` then the denominator will also be `100000` in other words the denominator in my code will always be such that the `i//denominator` will always yield a single digit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your string is going to have just floating number, then you can use [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) (*instead of [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)* which you have right now). Also, you need to make a chained call to it firstly with `'0'` and then with `'.'` like  `.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')` to handle the integers with trailing zeros like `10000`.

However, if you can have other characters in your string, and you want to strip `0` just for numbers, then you can use nested *f-string* as:

```
>>> f"{f'{1002/1000:.2f}'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')} number"
'1 number'

>>> f"{f'{1009/1000:.2f}'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')} number"
'1.01 number'

>>> f"{f'{1000:.2f}'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')} number"
'1000 number'
```

Comment: `rstrip` also gives me the same answer, any reason why I should not use what I already have?

Comment: Check the linked documents to each function. `strip()` removes the leading and trailing passed characters. `rstrip()` just removes the trailing characters which is what you need

Comment: a floating point number wont start with `.0` at least in my case it is guaranteed to be a float in the f string

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to work with two different format strings and `round` to detect when to use them:

```
for i in [1002, 1009]:
    print(f'{i/1000:.0f}') if round(i/1000, 2) == 1.00 else print(f'{i/1000:.2f}')
```

Which yields:

```
1
1.01
```

Refer to the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

> The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'f'` and `'F'`, or before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'g'` or `'G'`.

Depends on your matter of taste whether to use the `round` approach I suggest or the `strip` approach you're mentioning. If you're understanding Pythonic in the way that code should be clear, concise and maintainable then I'd use the `round` approach with the two format strings as it's very readable/understandable for future developers.

Comment: I did think about this, but it seems verbose, wanted to know if there were better ways

Comment: No unfortunately not, if you specify a format string with two decimal places Python will print them no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

When not supplying a format specifier, it appears that the formatter automatically simplifies. As such if one rounds the value before asking to format automatically, it gets closer to the desired result. It's not exactly what you asked for, but is simpler than the other answers. (I found my way to this question looking for this behaviour).

```
i = 1002
print(f'{round(i/1000, 2)}')  # 1.0

i = 1009
print(f'{round(i/1000, 2)}')  # 1.01
```

Demonstrated:

```
>>> i = 1002
>>> f'{round(i/1000,2)}'
'1.0'
>>> i = 1009
>>> f'{round(i/1000,2)}'
'1.01'
```

We can get what you actually wanted by leveraging your original idea / others' answers (only needing to provision for the whole-number cases):

```
i = 1002
print(f'{round(i/1000, 2)}'.rstrip('.0'))  # 1

i = 1009
print(f'{round(i/1000, 2)}'.rstrip('.0'))  # 1.01
```

Demonstrated:

```
>>> i = 1002
>>> f'{round(i/1000, 2)}'.rstrip('.0')
'1'
>>> i = 1009
>>> f'{round(i/1000, 2)}'.rstrip('.0')
'1.01'
```