# remove trailing zeros in float representation python

Tags: python, formatting, f-string

Using the f-string floating formatting I get the following results:

```
f"{1.34 :.2f}"  # 1.34
f"{1.30 :.2f}"  # 1.30
f"{1.00 :.2f}"  # 1.00
```

What I want however is to remove all trailing zeros:

```
f"{1.34 :.2f}"  # 1.34
f"{1.30 :.2f}"  # 1.3
f"{1.00 :.2f}"  # 1
```

Using complex functions I can strip zeros and possibly the decimal sign.
But it should be a common f-string notation, but I can't find it.

Comment: There isn't anything built in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66100708/how-to-skip-trailing-zeroes-from-decimal-in-pythons-f-strings

Comment: Okay, thank for the reply. Guess I'll keep the trailing zeros for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
my_float = 69.880

result = f'{str(my_float).rstrip("0").rstrip(".") if "." in str(my_float) else my_float}'

print(result)
```